# React application wont render Blog.js and PostDetails.js correctly

Tags: reactjs, json, create-react-app

I am working on a blog website using create-react-app.

I have a Blog.js file, which should render a PostList.js, Post.js which reads content from a local posts.json file that stores my posts. Once a user clicks on a Post that features inside the PostList I want to direct the user to a new subpage that shows the content from the PostDetails.js file.

However, when I start the development server and navigate to the Blog.js page nothing is rendered besides the Navbar and Footer. Any idea why that is? I would also like to know if my code looks correct given that I want to direct the user to a new page once they click on a post inside the Postlist.

I have attached the different files below, and at the very bottom is a visual of how the components are placed inside each other on the Blog.js page.

App.js

```
import Layout from "./components/layout/Layout";
import Blog  from "./Blog";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Contact from "./pages/Contact";
import Navbar from "./components/layout/Navbar";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import PostDetails from "./components/PostDetails";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <h1>SME Analyst</h1>
        <div className="App">
          <Navbar />
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />}/>
            <Route path="/blog" component={Blog} />
            <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />}/>
            <Route path="/blog/:postId" component={PostDetails} />
          </Routes>
          <Layout />
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Blog.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import PostList from './components/PostList';
import PostDetails from './components/PostDetails';

const Blog = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('./data/posts.json')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => setPosts(data));
  }, []);

  const handlePostClick = id => {
    // navigate to the subpage for the post with the specified id
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>My Blog</h1>
      <Route path="/blog/:postId" render={routeProps => <PostDetails {...routeProps} />} />
      <PostList posts={posts} onPostClick={handlePostClick} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Blog;
```

PostList.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Post from './Post';


const PostList = ({ posts, onPostClick }) => (
  <div>
    {posts.map(post => (
      <Post key={post.id} post={post} onClick={() => onPostClick(post.id)} />
    ))}
  </div>
);

export default PostList;
```

Post.js

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const Post = ({ post, onClick }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleClick = () => {
    navigate.push(`posts.json/${post.id}`); 
  };

  return (
    <div onClick={handleClick}>
      <h2>{post.title}</h2>
      <p>{post.content}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Post;
```

PostDetails.js

```
import React from 'react';
import getPostById from '../api';

const PostDetails = ({ postId }) => {
  const post = getPostById(postId); // this would be a function that retrieves the post with the specified id from your database or data store

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{post.title}</h1>
      <p>{post.content}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PostDetails;
```

posts.json

```
[
  {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Ecommerce and SMEs",
      "date": "04-01-2023",
      "summary": "Why Ecommerce and SMEs are a match made in heaven",
      "body": "Online commerce has become increasingly important for small businesses in recent years. It allows them to reach a wider audience, operate more efficiently, and gather data on customer behavior. It is an essential part of any small business' marketing and sales strategy, as it provides a cost-effective and efficient way to reach and sell to customers both locally and globally."
  },
  {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Blog Post 2",
      "date": "02-01-2023",
      "summary": "Lorem ipsum dolor",
      "body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nisl eros, pulvinar facilisis justo mollis, auctor consequat urna. Morbi a bibendum metus. Donec scelerisque sollicitudin enim eu venenatis. Duis tincidunt laoreet ex, in pretium orci vestibulum eget. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Duis pharetra luctus lacus ut vestibulum. Maecenas ipsum lacus, lacinia quis posuere ut, pulvinar vitae dolor. Integer eu nibh at nisi ullamcorper sagittis id vel leo. Integer feugiat faucibus libero, at maximus nisl suscipit posuere. Morbi nec enim nunc. Phasellus bibendum turpis ut ipsum egestas, sed sollicitudin elit convallis. Cras pharetra mi tristique sapien vestibulum lobortis. Nam eget bibendum metus, non dictum mauris. Nulla at tellus sagittis, viverra est a, bibendum metus."
  }
]
```

[Blog UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCIXE.png)

Comment: Looks like you re using react-domV6. The Route component API changed significantly from v5. A single element prop now replaced component, render, and children function, (and takes a JSX literal)  there are no longer any props to render a function in the Route, so you need to replaced all component in your Route to element, and check the React router dom documentation to see the breaking change and how to migrate between v5 to v6 properly

Comment: @ShueiYang thx for the help. Changing from component to element worked out.